# How to decode a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, decode

I have a WordPress plugin that I downloaded and need to make such changes to, but when looking at the code I see this:

```
 ${"\x47L\x4f\x42ALS"}["\x63e\x79\x6ah\x70\x77ub\x6f"]="c\x75\x73\x74om\x74\x79\x64\x6c\x63\x73\x73";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["i\x6db\x78\x6f\x62\x71"]="\x68e\x61\x64\x65r\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b";${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x6c\x74f\x63po"]="\x73\x75b\x68\x65\x61d\x6ci\x6ee";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4cS"}["\x72f\x78dx\x61\x75\x6f\x78\x6co"]="\x6d\x79\x5fpo\x73t";${"G\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6fqdz\x65f\x70\x74\x69\x72"]="p\x69d";${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x66\x75j\x64\x67\x7a"]="\x73qu\x65\x65ze\x70\x61\x67\x65\x74\x69tl\x65";${"G\x4c\x4fBA\x4c\x53"}....});}
```

Can anyone identify what kind of encoding that is an point me in the direction of a website that can decode it?

Note: I had to cut out some of the middle of the code because it was too long to post according to StackOverflow, but I'm sure you get the idea...  Thanks!

Comment: encoded? Or Obfuscated?

Comment: Sorry, looks more obfuscated to me!  I so couldn't remember what it was called when typing the message lol

Comment: Security through obscurity only seems to make whoever the code is being "hidden" from want to hack it apart that much more (much like anything released by M****soft). ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hex encode and the reverse is this: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=463d2f6124f0e50b67194fba93b8ab28

I really hate hate when programmers do this stupid kind of things! It's totally useless.

Comment: Very useless. They should just be happy their code is being used!

Comment: Just 'cause you can "decode" it in seconds, but its still a pain to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yah , its hex encode .  Its 100% useless . Some programmers think that encoding the source code using some easy to decode algrorithms for preventing code manifulation and outside interference ..

Decode it using this tool [Click here](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/)

N.B  - There are plenty of tools available in internet